# Vuex: store.state.activities has a key "list" that is an array of 3 items, however store.state.activities.list returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My project is in Vue.

`store.state.activities` is an object that has 2 keys, one of them is an array called `list` that has 3 items.

However, when I try to reference it using `store.state.activities.list`, I get an empty array.

I've tried making both a shallow and a deep copy of `store.state.activities`, in both cases the copy has an empty `list` array.

`store.state.activities` structure:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            // some data
        },
        {
            // some data
        },
        {
            // some data
        }
    ],
    "dictionaries": {}
}
```

`console.log(store.state.activities)` - you can see `list` has 3 items:
[image: store.state.activities]

whereas `store.state.activities.list` returns an empty array:
[image: store.state.activities.list]

Comment: Can you share the `store.state.activities` object code ? If it contains a list array. While accessing it should not be an empty. Please share some code how you are assigning properties in the `store.state.activities` object and how you are trying to retrieve

Comment: are you using the options or composition api? have you initialised the vuex to the application?

Answer (score 0):

the usual reasons for this are you've not initialised or accessed the vuex correctly

### initialising

is usually done in your main file and should look something like

```
import { store } from "../store";
createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .mount("#app");
```

---

### accessing

if you are using the Options API you have to access the store via the this in the components, which looks as so

```
this.$store.state.activities
```

if you are using the composition API however the this object is not available in which case you should do something like

```
import {useStore} from "vuex"
...
setup(){
    const store = useStore();
    return {
        activities : computed(()=>store.state.activities),
    ...
```

if you are just importing the store object you have defined then you will be getting a uninitialised version that wont be picking up any changes you make

if using type script the code is a little different

---

the final posibility i can think of is your assignment to the list property

if you are doing

```
this.$store.state.activities.list = [{},{}.{}];
```

then you will be replacing the list which will break the reference, assignment should be done via a mutator as vuex will wrap these changes in reactive wrapers that tell watchers of changes

```
mutations: {
    setList(state, value) {
        state.activities.list = value;
    },
    ...
},
```

which would then be called as

```
store.commit("setList", [{},{},{}]);
```